# JS/JQ: Access variable from inline function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm trying to use a variable inside my getJSON function. How can I pass it in? This is what I've tried.

```
function getComments(parent_id) {
    if(typeof(parent_id)==='undefined') parent_id = -1;
    console.log("parent_id type: " + typeof(parent_id)); // parent_id type: number 
    var message = { parentMessageID: parent_id };
    $.getJSON(UPDATECOMMENTCALL, message, function(data, parent_id) {
        console.log("JSON parent_id: " + typeof(parent_id)); // JSON parent_id: string
    }
}
```

Instead of parent_id being -1 inside the function, it's a string with value "success". How can I pass it in properly?

Comment: Your variable is already _global_, so you should be able to access it within the `.getJSON` call.

Comment: This all takes place inside a function. I'll add a bit more of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use it, don't put it as a parameter inside the callback function of the getJSON, just use it as a variable, because it's already global.

Comment: Wow, upvoted/accepted the answer that copied what @MelanciaUK said in the comments and what I described in detail in my answer... there is justice.

Answer (score 0):

You callback function parameter has a higher priority than the scope variable with the same name (`parent_id`). So by accessing it inside the callback function you're actually refering to the function parameter rather than the variable you've defined outside of the function. Changing the name of the callback variable will fix it. For example:

```
var parent_id = -1;    
console.log("parent_id type: " + typeof(parent_id)); // parent_id type: number 
var message = { parentMessageID: parent_id };
$.getJSON(UPDATECOMMENTCALL, message, function(data, p_id) { // changed to p_id
    console.log("JSON parent_id: " + typeof(parent_id)); // JSON parent_id: string
}
```

Generally, it's a good idea to avoid using the same names thus staying away from all the duplicate name mess.

---

Simple example to show you what's going on:

```
var a = 1;
function f(a) {
    console.log(a);
}
```

Think what will `f(2);` output.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Could be, the question is not the clearest. But I think OP wants to access the original parent_id inside the callback.